# Automount not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, samba

I'm trying to mount a windows share on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie.

As many others have stated, if I manually mount with `sudo mount -a` the volume mounts just fine. On a reboot, the mount fails.

I've tried the suggested fixes of:

1. `sudo crontab -e #` and adding `@reboot (sleep 30; /bin/mount /media/disk1)&`.
2. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and adding `mount -a` to the end of the file.
3. I tried to edit the fstab entry to include `comment=systemd.automount`.

None of this has worked. Does anyone have any other suggestions before I turn this Pi 3 into a range target?

Comment: Solved...I need to add _netdev, x-system.automount

I found numerous tutorials on mounting windows shares, but none of them contained that little gem above.  Thanks to lightswitch05 for the advice in another thread.